# Questions about Push and Local Notification [iOS 5 and above]

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I am still designing my application workflow and not starting the development yet. I wonder if this scenario can happen and not rejected by Apple:

- Receiving Push Notification or Local Notification
- Execute heavy task, for example, execute timer that will trigger `NSUrlConnection` or directly execute `NSUrlConnection`

Is it possible to execute some heavy operations after receiving notification?

**Update:**

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) , in part `Using Push Notifications to Initiate a Download`, it seems that download execution task is allowed in iOS 7, but I am not sure in iOS 5 & 6.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Using Push Notifications to Initiate a Download"(we called remote-notification background mode) is only available after iOS 7.0.
2. Without remote-notification background mode, if your app isn't in foreground, app's application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler will never be called until you tap the notification to make your app becomes to the foreground again.That means it is impossible to do something by notification when app isn't in foreground.

Comment: Isn't `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` will be called when PN comes? Btw, do you have experience on `Local Notification`?

Comment: the same,no method will be called when app isn't in foreground,no matter pn or ln!